# Low level android out of memory crashes using Realm

Tags: android, memory-management, out-of-memory, realm

I've been getting many OOM crashes in my android app (many but not all of them seem to be in Realm code:

#### First:

> io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. mmap() failed: Out of memory size: 872415232 offset: 0 in /Users/zaki/fromgit/realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 92

#### Second:

> io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. Too many open files in /Users/zaki/fromgit/realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 92

but also some even more vague memory issues:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Could not allocate JNI Env

These issues seem to only happen in production and watching the memory usage in my app seems to hover pretty consistently around 10MB.

Comment: You're not closing the Realm instances on the background threads.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce just to confirm the only thing i need to do is to pair every `Realm r = Realm.getDefaultInstance()` with a `r.close()` right?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah -  you might also be opening too many threads at the same time.

Comment: `Too many files open` indicate that you somehow are opening too many Realms as the system has run out of file descriptors. This could also explain the memory issues. Since Realm is caching Realms pr. thread this is either happening on different threads or because you are creating _many_ different Realms.