# How to debug: RealmError - Too many files open

Tags: android, realm

I have been building an application using Realm for a little while, I keep hitting this issue however.

I am currently using Realm Plugin: `io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.3.0`

Exception is:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.Error: io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. Too many open files in /home/cc/repo/realm/realm-java-release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 92
    at io.realm.AndroidNotifier.throwBackgroundException(AndroidNotifier.java:138)
    at io.realm.internal.async.QueryUpdateTask.run(QueryUpdateTask.java:128)
    at io.realm.internal.async.BgPriorityRunnable.run(BgPriorityRunnable.java:34)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. Too many open files in /home/cc/repo/realm/realm-java-release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 92
    at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.nativeGetSharedRealm(SharedRealm.java)
    at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.getInstance(SharedRealm.java:209)
    at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.getInstance(SharedRealm.java:186)
    at io.realm.internal.async.QueryUpdateTask.run(QueryUpdateTask.java:80)
    at io.realm.internal.async.BgPriorityRunnable.run(BgPriorityRunnable.java:34)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I have (while the app was running) queried the number of open files `adb shell ls -l /proc//fd`

When running I see a file `userxxx.management/access_control.new_commit.cv` is open 182 times and `userxxx.lock` is open 91 times.

Any hints or pointers would be appreciated!
Cheers,
Gavin

Comment: My guess goes for unclosed Realm instances, and randomly using `new Thread().start();` in places instead of some form of executor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check places, where you open an close realm instances. Same problem is described at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41154207/3926506).
Mr. [Christian Melchior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1389357/christian-melchior) explained cause of this error in comment:

> Too many files open indicate that you somehow are opening too many Realms as the system has run out of file descriptors. This could also explain the memory issues. Since Realm is caching Realms pr. thread this is either happening on different threads or because you are creating many different Realms. – Christian Melchior Dec 15 '16 at 10:11

Comment: I will post an update showing how I located my issues, but yes I had a lot more threads being opened than I expected, resulting in many more open Realms than was needed!

Answer (score 0):

So the way that I figured this one out was to use the Android Device Monitor and a little shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
my_watch () {
    tput sc
    pid=$1; while [ true ]; do
        tput rc; tput el
        printf "$2" `adb shell ls -l /proc/${pid}/fd | wc -l`
        sleep .1
    done
    tput rc; tput ed;
}

clear

APP_NAME=${1:?missing application name}

pid=`adb shell ps | grep $1 | awk '{print $2}'`

echo "Watch number of files in use for App: $1 PID: $pid - Ctrl-C to stop"
my_watch $pid "Files in use %s"
```

(Save the above in watch_usage.sh and execute using `./watch_usage.sh com.application.example` in a Terminal window, this will try and tell you the number of files that your application is using currently).

While the application was running, and I noticed that the number of files jumped, I then used the DDMS perspective of ADM to look at the current Thread listing. There was (in my case) a number of Threads for my RealmTransactionQueue (this should have been a singleton (and is now) however when I first created it I introduced a small bug that meant that it was getting new versions every now and again)... I could see this by looking at each Thread in the DDMS window and seeing where they started.

Thank you @sergey, your hunch was correct, this was due to out of control threading!

Hope the above helps someone in the future (if not me next time!).

Gav